# Will efficiency of SPDC to create entangled photon increase with resonance?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement

If I put a non linear crystal inside a resonant cavity will efficiency of SPDC process to create entangled photon pair increase? If so by how much? Is there any experimental data? I have this [paper](http://fisica.unipv.it/Nanophotonics/Pubs/HeltJOSAB2012.pdf) but I do not know if it has been experimentally verified.

Answer (score 1):

The efficiency of the process only depends on the phase matching and the non-linear coefficient of the crystal, and putting it in a cavity doesn't change that. However, putting it in a cavity will affect the output spectrum. There is work being done on this but as far as I know it's not published yet.

You could say that the efficiency increases with respect to the pump power, because the cavity traps the light and makes it pass through the crystal many times. This can be a useful effect, but it doesn't change the inherent efficiency of the process.